# How do you interact with Kafka server?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I've been looking into multiple Kafka tutorials and books and I see different ways by which they approach making producers/consumers, interacting with brokers etc. Some use `sh` files through command line, others tell you that you should write Java code and compile it.

What I'm wondering is: what is the preferred approach? And what is actually used the most in production?

Thanks.

Comment: it is depends on your needs, if you are writing java application which need to consume events and process them so use java library for this.
if you want to store database event binlog in Kafka  you can use Kafka connect plugin e.g Debezium ...

Comment: If you are confident with Spring, Go for spring-kafka, of course !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sh` files which you mention are the tools that are bundled with Kafka for testing and debugging purposes.

We use Kafka producers and consumers to build applications.

When you say production, you use Kafka in applications that produce to or consume from Kafka using Kafka clients API (or) Kafka Streams API or any other clients.

For debugging these applications, one can use these built-in tools. For example, to check if the messages are getting consumed or if the message content is as expected or not etc. These scripts are typically meant for simple use-cases.

For more advanced use-cases like writing automation suites etc, we have to use the clients API

Comment: Can't Kafka be used as a standalone data storage? (kinda like Elasticsearch is used like so even though it's usually used as a search box).

Comment: @Metric You still need an Elasticsearch server/cluster, similar to a Kafka broker cluster. Elasticsearch has a REST API and Java or other clients, similar to Kafka (minus REST)...

Comment: "When you say production, you use Kafka in applications that produce to or consume from Kafka using Kafka clients API (or) Kafka Streams API or any other clients." 

How does Kafka fit within an already existing Java application? I mean how can you integrate the two?

Comment: @Metrician you would have to use those clients, if at all you want to produce to or consume from i.e. you have to modify your application to use these clients.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I'd actually have to use the client APIs within the body of the application's code?

Comment: @Metrician yes, that is the way

Answer (score 3):

The `sh` files you mention are standard CLI utilities that come bundled with Kafka in the `/bin` directory. They are mostly used for administrative operations, but can also publish and consume messages as you pointed out. However, I have never seen anything serious built with them, unless you happen to be coding in Bash and need a quick way to publish a message.

Normally, the way to interact with Kafka brokers is via a client library distributed for whichever programming language you use. Think of Kafka as being like a database: you could use `psql` to interact with Postgres, which is very useful for interactively querying your tables, but to interact programmatically with a database you would need a JDBC or an ODBC driver. The client library is like a JDBC driver.

I'm a Java programmer, so I would use the standard Kafka library on [MavenCentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka).

Other languages, such as C#, Python and Golang, typically use a wrapper around the [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka) library.

Once you have imported your library (details are language-specific), you need to connect to Kafka. This is done by **bootstrapping** the client to a list of brokers. The client will try to connect to one of the brokers in the list, moving to the next if the broker is offline, and so forth. The bootstrapping mechanism is needed for fault-tolerance, as you don't want your application to stall if a broker fails.

To do all of this in Java, I would start by adding the Kafka library to my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then create a simple class for publishing a message periodically:

```java
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.*;

public class MyFirstProducer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final var topic = "my-first-topic";

    final Map<String, Object> config = 
        Map.of(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
               "localhost:9092", 
               ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
               StringSerializer.class.getName(), 
               ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
               StringSerializer.class.getName());

    try (var producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(config)) {
      while (true) {
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, "myKey", "hello Kafka"));
        Thread.sleep(500);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To consume messages from the topic:

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.*;

public class MyFirstConsumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var topic = "my-first-topic";

    final Map<String, Object> config = 
        Map.of(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
               "localhost:9092", 
               ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
               StringDeserializer.class.getName(), 
               ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
               StringDeserializer.class.getName(), 
               ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 
               "my-first-consumer",
               ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, 
               "earliest");

    try (var consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(config)) {
      consumer.subscribe(Set.of(topic));

      while (true) {
        final var records = consumer.poll();
        for (var record : records) {
          System.out.format("Got record with value %s%n", record.value());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Attributions: the examples above were taken from the book **Effective Kafka: A Hands-On Guide to Building Robust and Scalable Event-Driven Applications** by Emil Koutanov.